# Fusion Chart decimal formatting

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts

I'm using `Fusion Charts`. I need to display the data in Y as decimals below zero but they are not appearing kindly help.for example: how to display the decimals like 0.32 .34 in the chart

I've placed in my chart the following tags.

```
 forceYAxisValueDecimals='1' yAxisValueDecimals='1' decimals='1'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<chart decimals='3' sDecimals='2' forceDecimals='1'  >
```

Main Source For Above Answer is below link

http://kb.fusioncharts.com/questions/112/How+do+I+perform+Number+Formatting%3F

http://www.fusioncharts.com/docs/advanced/number-format/Number_Basics.html